# Dragging images

Tags: java, image

I am able to press and drag my image but however, when I press the center of the image, the cursor will always move to the upper top left of the image when I am dragging

This is what I mean with pictures

I pressed at the center of the image
[image]

The cursor will always move to the upper top left of the image when I am dragging
[image]

How do I make sure the cursor will be at the center of the image when I am dragging the image?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChessGUI extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    final int rows = 8;
    final int cols = 8;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int carx= 0;
    int cary =0;
    ImageIcon car;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int row = 0;  row < 8;  row++ ) {
            for (int col = 0;  col < 8;  col++ ) {
                x = 50*col;
                y = 50*row;
                if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
                    g.setColor(Color.white);
                else
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(x,y,50,50);
            }
        }
        car = new ImageIcon("resources/image/48/br.png");
        car.paintIcon(this, g, carx, cary);
    }

    public ChessGUI() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chess");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(420,450);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(new ChessGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
        carx = evt.getX();
        cary = evt.getY();
        repaint(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();   
        int y = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be as simple as reducing the `evt.getX();` and `evt.getY();` by a few pixels? It looks like the values return the right hand side of the mouse. Instead try setting `carx =evt.getX() - SOME_CONSTANT;`

Though be careful, mouse sizes could change depending on OS etc.

Comment: I think it's not that your mouse jumps to the top left corner, but you simply make the image appear where your mouse is by specifying image's top left corner. I mean your image position is determined by specifying its top left corner coordinates, and that's where your mouse is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cursor doesn't move to the upper left corner. What happens is your image moves its upper left corner to where your cursor is. This is because image's position is determined by specifying its upper left corner coordinates, so if you assign cursor coordinates to image's x and y, then image's upper left corner is drawn where your cursor is.

The solution would be to take the image's width and height, divide both values by 2, and then subtract from the cursor's coordinates before assigning them to the image's x and y. This would make the image center to always be where the cursor is.

Even better solution would be to find where exactly the cursor is in respect of the image at the time you click the cursor over the image and then adjust the cursor coordinates accordingly before assigning them to image's x and y.